# options_from_collection_for_select for relational model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Customer and Product with has_many associations.

Using options_from_collection_for_select I want to show the name of the products of each customer. I want to do something like this below

```
<%= select_tag(:customer_product, options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, @customers.products.id, @customers.products.name) )%>
```

or

```
  <%= select_tag(:customer_product, options_from_collection_for_select(@customers,:product.id, :product.name) )%>
```

I tried the second one and got this error

```
undefined method `id' for :product:Symbol
```

I want o know if something like this is possible. Or how can I achieve the above mentioned functionality easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@customers.products, 'id', 'name')
```

The first argument is a collection of items, the second and the third are the names of the attributes returning the id and the text.

References: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Answer (score 0):

As documented for [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), `options_from_collection_for_select` expects a `collection` as the 1st argument, `value_method` and `text_method` as the 2nd and 3rd arguments which will be called on the `collection`.

If you are passing `@customers` as the 1st argument, then you can only pass the attributes of the `Customer` as the 2nd and 3rd as follows:

`<%= select_tag(:customer_product, options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, 'id', 'name') )%>`

If you need to pass `@products` then first you need to setup the `@products` either through `ruby` like:

```
@products = @customers.inject([]).each do |all_products, customer_products|
  all_products << customer_products
end.flatten.uniq
```

Or, depending on your logic, you could even through `sql` itself.

Then use the following for your view:

```
<%= select_tag(:customer_product, options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'id', 'name') )%>
```